# How can I adjust my code to only call the API once in order to work around rate limits?

Tags: powershell, api, powerbi

I am using PowerShell to push data into Power Bi from a SQL Database. I am getting hit with a "Keyblocker error" and am told that this is due to a rate limit for this API. How can I adjust my code to append to a variable and make ONE call, as opposed to many?

```
$dataSource = '******' #Server Name
$userName = '****** ' #SQL User Name
$password = '************' #SQL User Password
$database = 'Production' #Database Name
#Uncomment below connection string to use windows credentials
#$connectionString = "Data Source=$dataSource;Initial Catalog=$database;Integrated 
Security=SSPI"
#Uncomment below connection string to use SQL Server authentication 
$connectionString ="Server=$dataSource;Database=$database;trusted_connection=false; user 
id =$userName;Password=$password;Integrated Security=False"
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
$query = '  
  SELECT [data],[datetime], [id], [source_id] FROM [dbo].[vwResawLine2FPM] 
  '
$command = $connection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $query
$dataset = $command.ExecuteReader()
#paste the endpoint URL which you have inside Power BI
$endpoint = "*****ENDPOINT*****"
#push data to Power BI 
while ($dataset.Read()) {
    $payload = @{
                "data" =$dataset['data']
                "datetime" =$dataset['datetime']
                "source_id" =$dataset['source_id']
        "id" =$dataset['id']
    } 
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload))
}
$connection.Close();
$connection.Dispose();
```

Comment: You can try to collect your data elements in an array and POST that JSON array instead of each individual element.

Comment: Is this a "Push Dataset" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/push-datasets-limitations  If so why not just have the dataset refresh from the SQL Server?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Yes, this is a push dataset. I want a live dashboard that populates as the most recent data comes into SQL without the end user needing to refresh. Is there an easier way to accomplish this that I am unaware of? This data is for Feet per Minute and I'd like it to be up-to-date at all times.

Comment: @stackprotector Ok, I see what you are saying. Would that involve me setting an empty array and then using a foreach loop to iterate through everything?
' ' ' $finaldataSet = @() 
foreach($object in $dataset){
 while ($dataset.Read()) {
    $payload = @{
                "data" =$dataset['data']
                "datetime" =$dataset['datetime']
                "source_id" =$dataset['source_id']
        "id" =$dataset['id']
    } 
    $finaldataSet.Append($object)
    }
    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$endpoint" -Body (ConvertTo-Json @($payload)) 
} ' ' '

Comment: With the last line needing to send $finaldataSet instead of $payload?

Answer (score 1):

> this is a push dataset. I want a live dashboard that populates as the most recent data comes into SQL without the end user needing to refresh.

Just use a [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about) Dataset, which enables the reports to read directly from the SQL Server database, and also enables [Automatic page refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-automatic-page-refresh).